# Java help regarding of arrays and printing out the individual lengths in the arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Currently, I have trouble attempting to print out the individual lengths efficiently.

`String[] array = {"test", "testing", "tests"};
int arraylength = array[0].length();
System.out.println(arraylength);`

Now, this does work in printing out the length however, it is inefficient and doesn't work if theoretically I don't know the length of the array.

Thanks for your input and I would appreciate if the code insisted contains "System.out.println" included so I don't have trouble figuring out which to print out.

Comment: The length of the array is `array.length`, `array[0].length()` is the length of the first `String`.

Comment: Okay thanks for your input but I wanted to know how to efficiently print out the array[#].length(). @ElliottFrisch

Comment: You want the length of each `String` in the array? You could use a `for-each` loop (there's already an answer with an example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
String[] array = {"test", "testing", "tests"};

for(String str : array) {
    System.out.println(str.length());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Very clarified for me now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8 then it's a one liner :)

```
    Arrays.asList(array).forEach(element -> System.out.println(element.length()));
```

What you are doing is, converting your array to a list and then running a for loop over it. Then for every element, you are printing out the length of the element.

**EDIT**

From one of the comment, this is even a better version of my code.

```
Arrays.stream(array).map(String::length).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here first you convert your array to a list and then map each element to the function length of string class, then you run a foreach over it which prints out the mapped values.

Comment: `Arrays.stream(array).map(String::length).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou awesome, I will edit my answer and add your solution too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 String[] array = {"test", "testing", "tests"};
```

The length for array is:

```
  int arraylength = array.length;
```

To have retrieve length for string:

```
 for(String string: array) {
System.out.println(string.length());
 }
```

Comment: Could you please indent your code, and change tring[] to String[] :p